# Spring profiles on integration tests class

Tags: spring, spring-test

we have selenium tests which are ran by java test class.

On local environment everything is ok, but I want to switch off those tests when run on jenkins.

So I use:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebIntegrationTest("server.port=1234")
@Profile("!jenkins")
@ActiveProfiles("integrationtests")
public class LoginAndEditProfileSeleniumTest {
...
```

What works:
running `mvn clean test` run all tests locally, with `integrationtests` profile active. I dont want to pass any additional parameter.

What I want to achieve:
running `mvn clean test -Dspring.profiles.active=jenkins` switch off this test.

Can I merge somehow profile passed by parameter, ActiveProfile annotation and take Profile annotation into consideration? :)

//update:
Its possible to use class extending ActiveProfilesResolver:

```
public class ActiveProfileResolver implements ActiveProfilesResolver {
@Override
public String[] resolve(Class<?> testClass) {

    final String profileFromConsole = System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active");
    List<String> activeProfiles = new ArrayList<>();
    activeProfiles.add("integrationtests");
    if("jenkins".contains(profileFromConsole)){
        activeProfiles.add("jenkins");
    }
    return activeProfiles.toArray(new String[activeProfiles.size()]);
}
}
```

but it seems to not to cooperate with @Profile anyway ( jenkins profile is active but test is still running ) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Profile` has **zero** affect on test classes. Thus, you should simply remove that annotation.

If you want to *enable* a test class only if a given system property is present with a specific value, you could use `@IfProfileValue`.

However, in your scenario, you want to *disable* a test class if a given system property is present with a specific value (i.e., if `spring.profiles.active` contains `jenkins`).

Instead of implementing a custom `ActiveProfileResolver`, a more elegant solution would be to use a JUnit *assumption* to cause the entire test class to be *ignored* if the assumption fails.

This should work nicely for you:

```java
import static org.junit.Assume.*;

// ...

@BeforeClass
public static void disableTestsOnCiServer() {
    String profilesFromConsole = System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active", "");
    assumeFalse(profilesFromConsole.contains("jenkins"));
}
```

Regards,

Sam (*author of the Spring TestContext Framework*)