# @IfProfileValue two spring profiles

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-boot, spring-profiles

Hello I have a springboot app and there are two possible spring profiles, one environment config related (dev,prod,staging...) and one with mocked some remote service, let's call it remoteServiceMock. So I have origin service that marked with :

```
@Profile("!remoteServiceMock")
```

And mock bean:

```
@Profile("remoteServiceMock")
```

Everything, except test are fine , when I run application with :

```
install -Dspring.profiles.active=dev,remoteServiceMock
```

or

```
install -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

So corresponding beans are loaded. But I got problems with testing.
My test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@Category({IntegrationTest.class})
@TestPropertySource("classpath:test.properties")
@IfProfileValue(name = "spring.profiles.active",
        values = "remoteServiceMock")
public class DeltaServiceMockTest {

    @Autowired
    private RemoteService remoteService;

    @Test
    public void shouldIntiService() throws Exception {
        assertNotNull(remoteService);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldGetMockDelta() throws Exception {
        RemoteData remoteDate = remoteService.getData(new Date(), new Date());
        assertEquals(15,remoteDate.getActivity().size());
    }
}
```

The problem that tests are being executed only if spring.profiles.active exactly match . So tests will run only if I will write:

```
@IfProfileValue(name = "spring.profiles.active", = "dev,remoteServiceMock")
```

The question are:

1) Is it possible to write some kind of extension for IfProfileValue with "contains"/"not contains" profile feature

2) Is the any other better solution for my goal ? (So I want to mock one (in feature there are several will be) of remote service and deploy my app to staging env).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into `@ActiveProfiles` feature and customize it based on [`ActiveProfilesResolver` (take a look at the bottom of this Spring docs section)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testcontext-ctx-management-env-profiles) .

Comment: Seems I was too sleepy and didn't find easy solution for skipping, like here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/32892291/3502543), but ActiveProfileResolver also fine for me :) Thanks a lot.